# What is exactly the requirements of CloudKit on iOS?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

Apple's documentation seems to say that CloudKit is available on iOS 8.0 and later. But when I test my app using CloudKit on iOS 8.1 and iOS 8.2 simulator, the CloudKit functions don't work. The ubiquityIdentityToken property of an NSFileManager is nil. But the CloudKit functions do work on iOS 8.3 simulator. And, when I had not updated the iCloud account to iCloud Drive, the CloudKit functions also don't work. They only work after I updated the iCloud account to iCloud Drive.

So, does CloudKit on iOS is only available to iOS 8.3 and later and for iCloud accounts that have been updated to iCloud Drive?

Comment: From my own experiments it appears Apple really wants everyone to upgrade to their iCloud account to iCloud Drive account. I notice the iCloud stuff doesn't work on iOS 8+ unless you upgrade the account: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971816/xcode-6-ios-8-icloud-core-data-setup So I think the short answer is Yes , you need iCloud Drive :D

Comment: But does it also need iOS 8.3 or later? Can't it work on iOS 8.0, 8.1 and 8.2?

Answer (score 0):

[CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html) provides authentication, a private and a public database, and structured asset storage services—so you can focus on client-side development.

Deploy the Development Environment to [**Production Environment**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html) in CloudKit dashboard.